# Detect when font changes in EPUB

Tags: javascript, viewport, font-size, epub, calibre

I am trying to use or create and event listener when the user changes the font size of the EPUB in an ereader with Javascript but I haven't find the way.

What I have tried without success:

- A `resize` event listener.
- A timing event that measures the font size.
- A listener that measures the scale of the `viewport`.

In `ebook-viewer` (aka Calibre viewer) I can see in the inspector that every time I change the font size the console prints `Viewport cfi: /2/4/2/2/1:1`. I see that when `1:1` changes, it's some sort of scale in int numbers.

That is why I tried to detect the viewport scale with [this](https://tombigel.github.io/detect-zoom/) or [this](http://menacingcloud.com/source/js/FlameViewportScale.js).

So I suppose it is possible only because I can see trough the inspector of `ebook-viewer`...

All the tries didn't work on iOS either.

**Update**

I know about the `epubReadingSystem` and its limitations. Also that JS is optional for EPUB3. What I am trying to solve is that in spanish poetry when a verse is larger that the box's size, it has to be a break and the next line has to be right aligned with a bracket:

`A short verse.
A very very long
         [verse.`

I figured out how to make this change. The issue is that when the user changes the font, the calculation has to be done again. I tried to solve this by doing a fixed EPUB, but iBooks and `ebook-viewer` allow the font increase...

A working example: jsfiddle.net/dxr9azy7

Answer (score 0):

There is no reliable way of doing what you want, where "reliable" means "working on any possible EPUB reading system". The reason is that the EPUB specification does not provide an official way for the document to "know" the properties of the context --- e.g., the current reading settings, like font size --- of the application rendering it.

Please note that Javascript support is not present in EPUB 2, and only optional in EPUB 3, and many reading systems restrict the type of Javascript code you can have inside your EPUB.

The EPUB 3 specification introduced a `epubReadingSystem` object for those reading systems that support Javascript, but it does not require that it should provide e.g. event bindings that can be used by JS code inside the EPUB to react to changes e.g. in the reading settings. (See: http://www.idpf.org/epub/31/spec/epub-contentdocs.html#app-epubReadingSystem )

On the other hand, since most reading systems are indeed built on top of rendering engines like WebKit, if they allows you to run Javascript, you can indeed do some "reverse engineering" and try to fish the correct global objects they maintain and the document model they use for displaying. With a bit of luck, you might be able to register your own bindings. However, this solution would require a lot of time to figure it out, it will work only on the given reading system(s) you tested, and it might break with app updated. In short, I do not recommend trying this route.

EDIT: BTW, what you are asking is similar to what I implemented in my own EPUB 3 reading app: https://www.readbeyond.it/minstrel/developers.html#js but unfortunately it is the only app (that I know of) that implements a mechanism establishing a communication channel between the JS inside the EPUB file and the reading system.

Comment: I updated the post to explain what I want to achieve that is the `onFontSizeChange` that you are implementing. So no known solution to this? In Minstrel how do you detect this change?

Comment: For what you want to achieve, your best bet is to use CSS, instead of JS. You might want to read http://epubsecrets.com/formatting-poetry-in-epub-part-1.php and http://epubsecrets.com/formatting-poetry-in-epub-part-2.php : these articles are old, but you can draw good ideas from them on how to format your poetry.

Comment: Minstrel is an hybrid app, so the "GUI" is actually HTML5 + JS running inside a WebView in a native app built by Cordova. So, when it opens an EPUB, it simply exposes a global ``epubReadingSystem`` object, and when an event occurs through the app GUI (e.g. user increases font => font size event), if there are callbacks registered by the JS code inside the EPUB on this global object, they are called. See https://github.com/readbeyond/minstrel/blob/master/cordova/src_minstrel/www/js/rb.epub.reader.js#L4283 and following lines. There is an example EPUB in the developers.html page.

Comment: I know about those links that you send. In english the format is called “[párrafo francés](http://glosariografico.com/parrafo_frances)” and it is easily achive with CSS. But in spanish it can't be achieved trough CSS. There is no seudo-selector to insert content after each auto break. Even in JS there is not a way to detect when and where does a paragraph breaks. At least as I have found, because I have been working in this issue several months ago and when finally I found a way to achieve this, I saw the problem posted here.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [this post](https://www.mobileread.com/forums/showthread.php?t=284969) we found a way **to detect the font size change in an EPUB**, at least in Calibre, ADE, and iBooks for Mac and iOS. It would be nice to try it in Readium and EPUBReader...

You have to create an iframe:

```
window.addEventListener("load", function () {
    iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
    iframe.id = "some_id";
    iframe.style.top = "0";
    iframe.style.left = "0";
    iframe.style.width = "100%";
    iframe.style.height = "5em";
    iframe.style.zIndex = "-1";
    iframe.style.visibility = "hidden";

    document.body.insertBefore(iframe, document.body.childNodes[0]);

    window.frames["some_id"].addEventListener("resize", function () {
        // Event when font size changes.
    });
});
```

If you are looking for a working script for spanish poetry, [see this](https://github.com/ColectivoPerroTriste/Herramientas/blob/master/EPUB/JavaScript/poetry.js). Download the sample: `mobileread.com/forums/attachment.php?attachmentid=155891&d=1490939383`.

Thanks!